# Count the number of repeating elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, hash

The question is to count the number of repeating elements in  the given array:

Suppose the input is:

- 1

```
1 2 3 3 3
```

- 2

```
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5
```

Then the output should be 3 for the first input and  5 for the second one.

I have written the code, according to logic its output should be 3 but I'm getting the output as 5 could anyone spot the error.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a[5] = {
    1,
    4,
    2,
    4,
    4
  };
  int b[101];
  memset(b, 0, 101);
  int cp = 0, i = 0;
  b[a[i]] = 1;

  for (int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {

    if (b[a[j] > 0]) {
      if (b[a[j]] == 1)
        cp++;
      cp++;
      b[a[j]]++;
    } else
      b[a[j]] = 1;

  }
  cout << cp;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memset(b,0,101)` does not zero the entire array, and will lead to undefined behaviour if you have values in `a` greater than 25. `int b[101] = {};` would avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code - you wrote `if(b[a[j]>0])` instead of `if (b[a[j]] > 0)`, which produces completely different behavior.

To avoid such mistakes, you should format your code properly and give meaningful names to variables. For example, your main function could be rewritten as:

```
int main() {
    const size_t SIZE = 5;
    int a[SIZE] = {1, 4, 2, 4, 4};
    const int MAX_VALUE = 100;
    int count[1 + MAX_VALUE] = {};
    int duplicates = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        if (count[a[j]] > 0)
            duplicates++;
        if (count[a[j]] == 1)
            duplicates++;

        count[a[j]]++;
    }

    cout << duplicates;
}
```

Note how I also removed a special case for the first array element - it is unnecessary and often prone to errors.

Answer (score 1):

If I read something like

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
```

and the variable names, then I assume that this question is related to some competetive programming site. So, my guess is that there are more constraints that we do not know. We see for example the magic number 101 here. Maybe there is a constraint that we have only integers in the range 0..100. Anyway, we do not know.

I would like to show a C++ solution. Basically this is using the standard approach for counting items, by using a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Please see the following code which basically consists of 2 lines. I will explain it afterwards:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <numeric>

std::vector testData{ 1,4,2,4,4 };

int main() {

    std::unordered_map<int, size_t> counter{};

    // Count the occurence of each integer value
    for (const int i : testData) counter[i]++;

    // Accumulate repeating values and show result
    std::cout << std::accumulate(counter.begin(), counter.end(), 0U, [](size_t c, const auto& p) { return c+(p.second > 1 ? p.second : 0U); });

    return 0;
}
```

As said, we use the standard approach with maps. The important point here is to understand the index operator of a map. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). And read:

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

The important point is: It will either return a reference to a value, if it is already in the map. If not, it will create the value in the map and again return a reference to the value. And because we get a reference to the value in any way, we can simply increment it.

After we have done this for all source values from our "testData"-vector in a very simple for loop, we have the count of all values. If the count for one value is greater then 1, then it is a duplicate or "repeated".

Therefore, we just need to accumulate all counters that are greater than 1. And for this we use the dedicated function `std::accumulate`.

If you should have any questions, then please ask.